# how to include a header file in VB

Tags: vb.net, file, header, include

I can write program VB 6.0, but I don't know how to include a file in VB 6.0.
In c it was

```
include "aa.h"
```

But I really don't know how to include this "aa.h" in my VB program.

Comment: goto this http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Interfacing_Visual_Basic_And_C.shtml might get help..

Answer (score 2):

Comments indicate that you are trying to share a variable between all modules. Just declare a Public variable in a .bas module:

```
Public foo As String
```

And, by the way, VB6 is *totally different* from C.

Comment: @Angela If my post has answered your question, you can "accept" the answer by ticking the large tick to the left of the post. The tick will go green.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The purpose of header files in C is to declare (function) prototypes for libraries that you use.

1. If your C function is available as a COM component (OCX), then you can use the OCX as an external component.
2. In classic Visual Basic (up to 6.0) you can declare dependencies to external libraries if those libraries reside inside DLLs. For this you must use the [declare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716201%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) feature of Visual Basic. This is basically the Visual Basic variant of the prototype used in the .h file. You must manually convert the C prototypes you want to use from the .h file to VB syntax: e.g. the C prototype `BOOL foo(LPCSTR lpString, HWND hWnd)` becomes `Declare Function foo Lib "a.dll" (ByVal lpString As String, ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long`
3. If your C functionality is a static libary (.lib), then you cannot use this libary directly. Instead, you must create a DLL or OCX out of it (using C), and use one of the above VB features for external dependencies.

Comment: my purpose to use an aa.h file was to share all the public variable . Those variable was share by all the module  (*.bas).

Comment: What should i do if I wana to share variable between modules(*.bas)?

Answer (score 0):

Goto

> Menu -> Projects -> Components

and choose from the list of `Components` available

or for adding references

> Menu -> Projects -> References

and choose from the list of `References` available

and call/declare it like

```
Dim comp as YourComponent
```

Comment: I am sorry that I don't unstand. I just want to share all the public variable for all the modules(*.bas).Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only available solution close to C include headers is to add a module with all your declares and shared variables.

For example:

Public variable1, variable2 as string...
Declare Function X alias Y...